# Problema no SDK PHP do Facebook no PHP 8.1. Como corrigir?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte erro no SDK PHP do facebook, após atualizar a versão do php para 8.1.

> Deprecated: Facebook\FacebookApp implements the Serializable interface, which is deprecated. Implement __serialize() and __unserialize() instead (or in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/includes/class/Facebook/FacebookApp.php on line 29

No arquivo *FacebookApp.php*, fiz as seguintes alterações nas funções serialize() and unserialize():

```
    <?php
    public function __serialize(): array
    {
        return implode('|', [$this->id, $this->secret]);
    }

    /**
     * Unserializes a string as a FacebookApp entity.
     *
     * @param string $serialized
     */
    public function __unserialize(array $serialized): void
    {
        list($id, $secret) = explode('|', $serialized);
        $this->__construct($id, $secret);
    }
    ?>
```

Após fazer isso, recebo o erro:

> Fatal error: Class Facebook\FacebookApp contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Serializable::serialize, Serializable::unserialize) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/includes/class/Facebook/FacebookApp.php on line 29

Não sei como fazer as devidas correções. Pode me ajudar? Abaixo, deixo o código original do *FacebookApp.php* completo. Gostaria de aprender a corrigir.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2017 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to
 * use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary
 * form for use in connection with the web services and APIs provided by
 * Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use
 * of this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and
 * Policies [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice
 * shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
 * DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */
namespace Facebook;

use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

class FacebookApp implements \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var string The app ID.
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string The app secret.
     */
    protected $secret;

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @param string $secret
     *
     * @throws FacebookSDKException
     */
    public function __construct($id, $secret)
    {
        if (!is_string($id)
          // Keeping this for BC. Integers greater than PHP_INT_MAX will make is_int() return false
          && !is_int($id)) {
            throw new FacebookSDKException('The "app_id" must be formatted as a string since many app ID\'s are greater than PHP_INT_MAX on some systems.');
        }
        // We cast as a string in case a valid int was set on a 64-bit system and this is unserialised on a 32-bit system
        $this->id = (string) $id;
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the app ID.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the app secret.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSecret()
    {
        return $this->secret;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an app access token.
     *
     * @return AccessToken
     */
    public function getAccessToken()
    {
        return new AccessToken($this->id . '|' . $this->secret);
    }

    /**
     * Serializes the FacebookApp entity as a string.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return implode('|', [$this->id, $this->secret]);
    }

    /**
     * Unserializes a string as a FacebookApp entity.
     *
     * @param string $serialized
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list($id, $secret) = explode('|', $serialized);

        $this->__construct($id, $secret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tente manter os dois métodos, com e sem __ no início. De qualquer forma, parece que o sdk não suporta essa versão do php. Eu procuraria uma versão mais novo do sdk ou usaria um php mais antigo. Código de biblioteca não é pra ficar editando. E mesmo consertando esse ponto, podem aparecer outras incompatibilidades

Comment: ai que tá o problema, o facebook parece que abandonou o sdk php. Não atualiza faz um bom tempo.

Comment: Sua recomendação funcionou pra mim. Você pode publicar uma resposta para eu marcar como resolvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer o que sugere a mensagem de erro: manter os dois métodos, com e sem `__` no início:

> (...) instead (or in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary)

De qualquer forma, parece que o SDK não suporta essa versão do php. Eu procuraria uma versão mais nova do SDK, ou usaria um PHP mais antigo. Código de biblioteca não é pra ficar editando. Mesmo consertando esse ponto, podem aparecer outras incompatibilidades.